# Problema con css

Tags: php, html, css, css3

Tengo el siguiente codigo css

```css
<style>
p {
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: inter-word;
}
</style>
```

Pero lo quiero solo para esta parte del documento en html

```html
<p  style="margin-top: 20px; line-height: normal;"><font size=2><strong>Herramientas</strong>: Se realiza entrega de computador port&aacute;til marca <strong>HP</strong> serie <strong>'.$Equipo .'</strong>, con n&uacute;mero de serial<strong>'.$Serial .'</strong>, con las siguientes caracter&iacute;sticas de hardware: procesador Intel core i5 6200u gen 6, memoria ram ddr 3 de 8 gb,disco duro de 500 gb de almacenamiento, pantalla antirreflejo de 15, color de equipo negro se encuentra en un estado de <strong>usado</strong>.</p>

<p  style="margin-top: 20px; line-height: normal;"><font size=2><strong>Servicios:</strong> precargado con los siguiente software&acute;s: Windows 7 profesional, office 2016 home &amp; business, winrar, vlc, Skype, adobe reader, adatec para pc, Firefox, Chrome, plugins de navegaci&oacute;n, configuraciones, impresoras locales de oficinas swisslub, correo corporativo en pc y dispositivo m&oacute;vil, redes wifi y LAN.</p>

<p  style="margin-top: 20px; line-height: normal;"><font size=2>Usted como usuario asume la completa y total responsabilidad en caso de da&ntilde;o, perdida y deterioro del equipo entregado, fuera del deterioro normal con buen uso del equipo. <span style="color: black;">Este</span><span style="color: black; letter-spacing: 0pt;"> equipo es una estaci&oacute;n de trabajo que SWISSLUB S.A.S. est&aacute; poniendo a su disposici&oacute;n para uso dentro de sus oficinas; en caso31 de requerir trasladarlo quedar&aacute; bajo su riesgo y responsabilidad; esto quiere decir que, si el equipo sufre alg&uacute;n da&ntilde;o o perdida, usted deber&aacute; pagar el reemplazo del equipo, inmediatamente. Por lo cual, con su firma, a que los eventos detallados anteriormente, el valor del equipo le sea, descontado de n&oacute;mina o en caso de retiro de su liquidaci&oacute;n definitiva. Asimismo, el costo de reparaci&oacute;n o cambio de elemento da&ntilde;ado o perdido, siempre y cuando este da&ntilde;o no provenga del desgaste natural del equipo.</span></p>

<p style="margin-top: 20px; line-height: normal;"><font size=2> <span style="color: black; letter-spacing: 0pt;">La estaci&oacute;n de trabajo, solo funcionar&aacute; y deber&aacute; funcionar exclusivamente en el desarrollo de las actividades inherentes a su cargo. La informaci&oacute;n que se genere en el desarrollo de sus actividades como funcionario de la compa&ntilde;&iacute;a, estar&aacute;n alojadas en el equipo c&oacute;mputo perteneciente a <strong>SWISSLUB S.A.S.</strong>, prohibi&eacute;ndose su copiado y/o distribuci&oacute;n de las mismas a otros medios de almacenamiento, comunicaci&oacute;n a personas y segregaci&oacute;n de esta informaci&oacute;n; acorde a lo estipulado en la cl&aacute;usula segunda numeral dieciocho de sus obligaciones contractuales suscritas en su contrato de trabajo y reglamento interno de trabajo, articulo 45 numeral 1. De ninguna manera el equipo ser&aacute; utilizado para trabajo personal, almacenamiento de informaci&oacute;n personal y/o desarrollo recreativo; esta rotundamente prohibido la instalaci&oacute;n de software adicional sin autorizaci&oacute;n del Departamento de las TIC &ldquo;tecnolog&iacute;as de la informaci&oacute;n y la comunicaci&oacute;n&rdquo;; acorde a lo estipulado en la cl&aacute;usula segunda numeral diecisiete de sus obligaciones contractuales suscritas en su contrato de trabajo y reglamento interno de trabajo, articulo 45 numeral 9.</span></p>

<p  style="margin-top: 20px; line-height: normal;"><font size=2><span style="color: black; letter-spacing: 0pt;">Adicionalmente est&aacute; prohibido subir o bajar de Internet, m&uacute;sica y otros archivos ajenos al trabajo. Si el equipo muestra da&ntilde;o o mal funcionamiento por causa de archivos mal intencionados, y se encuentra m&uacute;sica o archivos ajenos al trabajo de la compa&ntilde;&iacute;a, los costos por reparaci&oacute;n y mantenimiento reinstalaci&oacute;n del sistema operativo y de los dem&aacute;s programas estar&aacute;n a su cargo.</span></p>

<p style="margin-top: 20px; text-align: justify;"><span style="font-size: 10.0pt;">Observaciones: </span></p>

<table style="border-collapse: collapse; margin-left: 4.8pt; margin-right: 4.8pt;" width="525">
<tbody>
<tr style="height: 6.2pt;">
<td style="width: 119.25pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 6.2pt;" width="192">
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;">&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
<tr style="height: 6.2pt;">
<td style="width: 100.25pt; border: none; border-bottom: solid windowtext 1.0pt; padding: 0cm 0cm 0cm 0cm; height: 6.2pt;" width="192">
<p style="margin-bottom: .0001pt; line-height: normal;">&nbsp;</p>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</font>
```

pero me lo pone incluso para arriba del documento y no se como cuadrarlo

Comment: ¿Para cuál parte? No queda claro

Comment: sorry parala que subi despues para todos los <p>

Comment: Pues simplemente asigna una clase a los <p> que quieres que tengan esos estilos, y en tu css cambias el selector de etiqueta a clase y listo

Comment: la etiqueta es . o #

Comment: Asigna una clase a los <p> y en css los capturas con un . y el nombre de la clase

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando te encuentras con este problema de estilos que tienes es necesario empezar a seleccionar elementos ya sea por **CLASS** o por **ID**, las buenas prácticas dictan que cuando vas a tener un elemento con un nombre único dentro del sitio debes usar **ID** pero cuando varios elementos van a compartir en mismo nombre entonces debes usar **CLASS**

> No está bien visto que en una misma página se repita un mismo **ID** en varios elementos.

Ahora para seleccionar en un archivo css un elemento por su atributo **CLASS** solo basta colocas un punto (.) seguido del nombre que has asignado a dicho atributo.

```css
p{
    color: black;
}

.parrafo{
    color: chocolate;
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<p>Este es un párrafo normal</p>
<p class="parrafo">Este es un párrafo con class</p>
<p>Este es un párrafo normal</p>
<p class="parrafo">Este es un párrafo con class</p>
<p>Este es un párrafo normal</p>
<p class="parrafo">Este es un párrafo con class</p>
<p>Este es un párrafo normal</p>
```

Como puedes ver en este sencillo ejemplo que te coloco he utilizado una clase para "separar" los estilos de unos párrafos con otros, que es justamente lo que tú necesitas.